# Why FrameSelected Numpad. (Full Stop) is considering always the center of the grid?

Tags: interface, shortcut

I'm having an annoying issue with the full stop/period key shortcut.

When I use the full stop the viewport always consider the origin to centralize. I tried to reset de preferences without success.

And this is happening only in a specific project, the most important ofc :(, and seems that in some point I did some change accidentally, because if a get an older version/backup of the project it doesn't happen.

What did I change to get this weird behaviour?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: That's how the period key is supposed to work if you have the cursor in the 3D view, - It centres the pivot point in the viewport. As you say, it will centre the selected frame in the Dope Sheet (or the selected object in the Outliner) if that's where the cursor is when you press the key. If it's doing different things in different projects, compare the settings in the preferences keymap to see if they're different.

Comment: Where is the object origin located? In object mode that is where this function will move to.